# XCode can't fix landscape orientation layout in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, xcode-storyboard, landscape-portrait

I have a simple linear chain of UIViewControllers.
The first one has a show segue to a NavigationViewController, then it goes on the same way with all the others.

When I switch from wCompact-hRegular to wRegular-hCompact to fix the landscape layouts the first viewcontroller doesn't allow me to do anything. The tree diagram at the left side of the storyboard screen shows the views but they are not written in black. They are transparent. Even if I select them and put the coordinates or dimensions nothing happens. There are only a button and a label. Others Controllers are all ok, they can be fixed. What is happening to the first one?

Comment: Add a screen from the storyboard, please.

Comment: I can't but it's simple, UIViewController --> NavigationViewController --> UIViewcontroller, where --> are show segues. The first one has only a button and label at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XCode 6 you can add views, that are only visible in the selected size class (f.e. Compact + Compact). When you change to a different size class the views are disabled. To fix this navigate to the attributes inspector and select `installed` for any class sizes.
[image]